# Get selected buttons of btn-group (buttons-checkbox) with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-filter, buttongroup

I'm using bootstrap and angular to build an application. In a HTML page, i'm using this:

```
<div class="btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn fzbtn-consServices" ng-repeat="service in availability.services">{{service.name}}</button>
</div>
```

It's building a button group with dynamic values. Is there a practical way to obtain the selected buttons inside this button group?

I already tried some solutions, some of them are working but I don't know if it's the best way...
1: On "ng-click" method I would change a attribute value (eg. "checked" attribute) of each service to true or false;
2: I searched about any html attribute for btn-group which could offer me all the selected buttons inside this group, but i had no success;
3: I heard that i could beat this problem using Angular Filter, but i didn't find any similar example;

Anyone with a better idea? Thanks so much :)

This is the best solution I found until now:

```
<div class="btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn fzbtn-consServices" ng-repeat="service in availability.services" ng-click="onClickService(service)" ng->{{service.name}}</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.onClickService = function (service) {
        if (service.checked) {
            service.checked = "false"
        } else {
            service.checked = "true";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer: **Bootstrap UI**

I feel your pain. Bootstrap is not always angular-friendly. But there is a good solution:

The easiest (and by far the cleanest) approach is to use [Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap). Built by the Angular Team, it is a rewrite of the javascript-portion of Bootstrap but for an Angular-friendly usage. Here's the section about buttons: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons

### Example solution: Checkbox button behavior

In this solution, the initial services array is used to store a boolean field 'selected' to know if any particular service is selected or not. (Similar to the "checked" in the question). This field is 2-way bounded to the checkbox state. Clicking the checkbox changes the field and changing the field changes the checkbox state.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  var services = [ 
    { name:'Service A' },
    { name:'Service B', selected:true },
    { name:'Service C' },
    { name:'Service D', selected:true }
  ];
  
  $scope.availability = { services:services };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS BootStrap UI radios</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group-justified">
    <label ng-repeat="service in availability.services" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="service.selected" btn-checkbox>{{service.name}}</label>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="service in availability.services">{{service.name}} <span ng-show="service.selected">- selected</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Radio button behavior

I've included a solution for a "single selection" checkbox also known as a "radio-button". The "current selection" is bound to a variable on the scope. It will get updated automatically when the user picks an element. Setting it will, in turn, change the current selection.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  var services = [ 
    { name:'Service A' },
    { name:'Service B' },
    { name:'Service C' },
    { name:'Service D' }
  ];
  
  $scope.availability = { services:services };
  $scope.model = {};
  
  // Here we are using the service object instance as the "selection value". 
  // Depending on what you need, you could also use some sort of identifier or 
  // even the $index if that's more useful.
  
  // Immediately select the second one.
  $scope.model.selectedService = services[1];
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS BootStrap UI radios</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group-justified">
    <label ng-repeat="service in availability.services" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="model.selectedService" btn-radio="service">{{service.name}}</label>
  </div>
  <div>Current Selection is: {{model.selectedService.name}}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

NOTE: I used `<label>` instead of `<button>`, but I did not have your special CSS styles so it wasn't behaving on the screen, functionality-wise it works equally well with `<button>` elements.

Comment: Thank, Bernard. What i really want is a behavior like checkbox, because I need to select many buttons. Could you post the solution for checkbox use?

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I inferred "radio" simply because you said you wanted to know which one was selected. (which is what radio is all about). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: answer edited to show off a "checkbox"-style solution -- it is actually simpler since it reuses the original services array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really specify why you are wanting to "get" the buttons. In general, getting a reference to DOM elements like this is not the "angular way." It is generally better to find a way to use angular's data-binding to manipulate UI elements.

For instance, if you want to show or hide buttons based on data or on another UI event, then use ng-show or ng-hide bound to a property of the service object you are binding these buttons to. Then you can update the object's property to change the UI. You should be able to find a similar way to make other changes (like setting classes, attributes, etc.) with angular's data-binding rather than doing it manually.

Comment: I want to "get" the buttons because i need to consume a rest webservice informing the ID of which "services" were selected.  
I can'f find a way to bind this information that I need... this is why i'm asking for a better solution :)  
Thanks for the help